# Trapped in square; Who am I?

Tags: riddle

Mortals, beware!
A divine trapped in square!

Only silences to your prayers,
Until a step through the stairs.

Powers to make you a millionaire,
The only one with a spear.

Beneath the future heir,
Four does not make 2 pairs!

Hint #1

> "**Beneath**" the future heir is relevance; The line can be replaced by "**After**" the future heir

Hint #2

> The only one with spear; *She* (hehe) is the only one that has a weapon!

Comment: Consistent with site practice, I have changed your title to be more unique.  If you would like something different, feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks, no further change is required, I'll let it stay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is:

> Queen of Spades

Mortals, beware!
A divine trapped in square!

> Royalty used to be considered divinity. Playing cards are rectilinear, which is close enough to square.

Only silences to your prayers,

> Luck at cards are determined by fate, not prayers.

Until a step through the stairs.

> Not a clue what this means.

Powers to make you a millionaire,

> You can win big at cards.

The only one with a spear.

> Some cards have a distinctive design where the Queen of Spades is holding a scepter that kind of looks like a spear.

Beneath the future heir,

> You say that beneath can me after, in your hint, and a Queen would assume the throne only after the Prince (Jack) in many monarchies.

Four does not make 2 pairs!

> Well, there's lots of parses for this. None of which make sense to me...but 2 pairs is the biggest clue we're dealing with playing cards.

Comment: This was my guess too. A few other reasons: spades are also known as pikes (aka spears), the queen of spades is known as "Pallas" (another name for the goddess Athena, so definitely devine).

Comment: The answer is close enough that I will accept it as correct!  IT's Athena that I am looking for indeed.  To add to your answer, ***Queen of Spades is actually referring to [Athena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_%28playing_card%29), the only Queen that holds a weapon***

Answer (score 3):

I'll go for

> playing cards.

*Mortals, beware!

 A divine trapped in square!*

> Playing cards are rectangular (close enough to square). The "divine" bit could be a reference to *tarot* cards.

*Only silences to your prayers,*

> You might pray to win a game of cards...

*Until a step through the stairs.*

> ... but only luck will see your prayers answered.

*Powers to make you an millionaire,

The only one with a spear.*

> If your luck runs good (or you cheat, or you run a casino)$^1$, you can become a millionaire by playing cards. Many games have only one winner.

*Beneath the future heir,*

> The Jack or Knave in a given suit can sometimes be called the Prince, heir to the throne.

*Four does not make 2 pairs!*

> Four suits in a pack of cards.

$^1$ Well, OK, the two possibilities in brackets are the only real ways of doing it, unless your name's Mat Cauthon.

Comment: sounds very plausible :) might be it

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi I like your answer too :-)

Comment: I was just going to write playing cards, just 5 hours late :P

Comment: Very close, actually you are looking at the answer without knowing!

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> Poker

Mortals, beware!
A divine trapped in square!

> A square poker table

Only silences to your prayers,
Until a step through the stairs.

> People pray silently, not sure about stairs

Powers to make you an millionaire,
The only one with a spear.

> It can get you a lot of money or can kill you.

Beneath the future heir,
Four does not make 2 pairs!

> A 4 of a kind is different from 2 double pairs

Comment: Very close, actually you are looking at the answer without knowing!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> The spear maiden in The Arthurian Tarot

\

> The spear maiden is associated with the element of fire; being also the Manasic fire - born of the Buddhic earth of primal darkness. In this respect we find her roots in the myth of Ariadne, who gave to the hero Theseus, the intuitive thread that would guide him through the labyrinth. In the grail legends we meet her again in the form of a mysterious girl who at first snubs Perceval and when he tries to follow her, he looses her in the pitch black darkness of the night. He then sees a vision of a supernatural light, which burns like five lit candles, lighting up the forest. When it is daybreak Perceval catches up with the maiden, who has now changed in favour towards him and gives to Perceval a ring and a white mule, that she says, will lead him to the grail. The ring is of course, another aspect of the spear Hallow.

Comment: Nope but you're in the correct direction; *not Tarot* =)

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, but I'll say,

> a dream

because:

Mortals, beware! A divine trapped in square!

> the dream comes when you are trapped in the square pillow

Only silences to your prayers, Until a step through the stairs.

> before the dream it is silent, until the dream starts

Powers to make you an millionaire, The only one with a spear.

> in the dream you can be everything you want (a millionaire, for example) or you can be the only one with a given knowledge

Beneath the future heir, Four does not make 2 pairs!

> the four sides of the pillow or the bed are equal, so they are not 2 pairs

Comment: Nice thought, although it's not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

It may be

> Her majesty Queen Elizabeth II.

Mortals, beware!
A divine trapped in square!

> The queen lives in Buckingham Palace, which has a square shape. She's also considered like a "goddess" by English people.

Only silences to your prayers,
Until a step through the stairs.

> This is still obscure to me.

Powers to make you a millionaire,
The only one with a spear.

> She is very very rich. She also lives in England, homeland of Shake**spear**e

Beneath the future heir,
Four does not make 2 pairs!

> She has four children, 3 males and a female, so no pairs.

Comment: Good guess but not correct;  However I see the answer in the **two words combined in your first two lines of answer**

Comment: @Alex What do you count as the first two lines? "It may be"+spoiler? First two spoilers? If the former, could the answer be a **queen bee**?

Comment: I already thought of Queen Bee, but there are too many elements not matching (divine, square, prayers, stairs, millionaire, four and 2 pairs)...